# Does EMF (Enhanced Metafile) support opacity?

Tags: transparency, opacity, image-formats, .emf

I would be able to create an EMF image (programmatically or from a software) having the background color 50% transparent and the other elements completely opaques.

I'm already be able to create a background completely transparent, but not with a certain alpha/opacity.

Creating this semi-transparent background would allow to overlay the image to another background without completely hide it.

Does anyone know if it's possible with the Enhanced Metafile format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no: EMF (or WMF) image format supports full transparency but not opacity between 0.0 and 1.0 because it doesn't support colors with alpha channel.

[Here are image formats that supports alpha channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_graphics_file_formats)

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with this topic a few weeks now and my research led me to good results.
Here is information for those who might face this issue in the future:

Windows EMF which uses GDI library does not support transparent colors.
However there is a newer EMF format called EMF+, which uses GDI+ library and supports transparency.

Here is the [documentation of the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There are quite a few examples for these metafiles in C++ arround the internet, but some experiments can lead you the right way.